# Recover Raspi SSH after assigning wrong router IP

Tags: raspbian, headless

I have lost ability to connect to my Raspi which I have connected via ethernet to my router after I believe I have assigned the wrong router IP address in /etc/network/interfaces file.

I normally connect to it over my wlan via headless putty interface and lost ability to connect after attempting to assign a static IP address and disabling DHCP service and enabling networking service.

Is the only way to solve this to use a mouse/keyboard and monitor to log into my raspberry pi?

Comment: It depends on whether you know *exactly* what IP address and subnet mask you assigned to the device. Do you?

Comment: can you connect to raspberrypi.local ?

Comment: If you have a keyboard and mouse, you can login.